# Join 3 tables of users, friends, chats

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I just want to get the result of a single user's friends and for each friend to join the last timestamp of the chat between the user and the friend:

User friends list:

- Friend1: fname, lname,...., chat timestamp
- Friend2: fname, lname,...., chat timestamp
- ...

`users` table is the main user information table:

usr_id,usr_fname,usr_lname

`friends` table is a table containing the friendships:

frd_id, frd_usr_id1, frd_usr_id2

`chats` table is a table containing chats between users:

cht_id, cht_usr_id1,cht_usr_id2,cht_timestamp

**Can anyone help me with SQL statements?**

**Let say that the requesting user ID is in $user_id variable**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
SELECT f.frd_id, u.usr_id, u.usr_fname, u.usr_lname, MAX(c.cht_timestamp)
FROM friends AS f
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.usr_id IN (
SELECT u1.usr_id FROM users AS u1 WHERE u1.usr_id != $user_id)
LEFT JOIN chats AS c ON ( (c.cht_usr_id1=$user_id AND c.cht_usr_id2=u.usr_id) OR
      (c.cht_usr_id1=u.usr_id AND c.cht_usr_id2=$user_id) )
    WHERE ( (f.frd_usr_id1=$user_id AND f.frd_usr_id2=u.usr_id) OR
    (f.frd_usr_id1=u.usr_id AND f.frd_usr_id2=$user_id) )
    GROUP BY u.usr_id ORDER BY  MAX(c.cht_timestamp) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work...

```
SELECT u1.usr_fname [Friend1First], 
    u1.usr_lname [Friend1Last], 
    u2.usr_fname [Friend2First], 
    u2.usr_lname [Friend2Last], 
    MAX(ch.cht_timestamp) [LastChatTime]
FROM Chats ch
    JOIN users u1 ON ch.cht_usr_id1 = u1.usr_id
    JOIN users u2 ON ch.cht_usr_id2 = u2.usr_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT frd_id from friends fs WHERE (fs.frd_usr_id1 = a.usr_id AND fs.frd_usr_id2 = b.usr_id) 
                    OR (fs.frd_usr_id2 = a.usr_id AND fs.frd_usr_id1 = b.usr_id))
GROUP BY u1.usr_fname, u1.usr_lname, u2.usr_fname, u2.usr_lname,
```